# React.js, why my class component doesn't rerender the element, but functional component can work?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react.js, just follow the tutorial. Here is my code. At first, i tried to use the class Component 'Greeting' to let it show different words after
clicked the button, but i don't know what's wrong, it doesn't rerender the element, and the construtor() method of Greeting only called once. The commented out code functional Component 'Greeting' works well. Not sure what's the difference :(

```
class GreetingGuest extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h3>hello Guest, Click login button !!! </h3>
        );
    }
}

class GreetingUser extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h3>You have logged in, welcome !!!</h3>
        );
    }
}

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);   
      console.log('Greeting.state.is_logon = ', props.is_logon);
      this.state = {is_logon: props.is_logon};
  }

  render() {
      let welcome_msg = null;
      if (this.state.is_logon) {
          welcome_msg = <GreetingUser />;                 
      }else {
          welcome_msg = <GreetingGuest />;    
      }
      return welcome_msg; 
  }
}

//function Greeting(props) {
//    const is_logon = props.is_logon;
//    if (is_logon) {
//        return <GreetingUser />;
//    }
//    return <GreetingGuest />;
//}

class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {        
        super(props);           
        this.state = {is_logon: false};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            is_logon: !prevState.is_logon
        }));
    }

    render() {
        let button = null;
        let greeting = null;

        if (this.state.is_logon) {
            button = (
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Logout</button>
            );

            greeting = <Greeting is_logon={this.state.is_logon} />
        }else {
            button = (
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Login</button>
            );
            greeting = <Greeting is_logon={this.state.is_logon} />
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {greeting}
                {button}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <LoginComponent />,
    document.getElementById('Login')
)
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
     <div id="Login"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the class component doesn't re render, is because you have stored the `logged_in` prop in state from the constructor, and the constructor is only called once. Also state can only be modified from within the component.

To fix this you have 2 options;

#### Use `componentWillReceiveProps`, and update the local state with the new `logged_in` prop.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.logged_in !== this.state.logged_in) {
    this.setState({ logged_in: nextProps.logged_in });
  }
}
```

#### Or; do not use state but use the prop directly.

```
  render() {
      let welcome_msg = null;
      if (this.props.is_logon) {
          welcome_msg = <GreetingUser />;                 
      }else {
          welcome_msg = <GreetingGuest />;    
      }
      return welcome_msg; 
  }
```

Where I think you should use the latter, since the parent component already maintains state.

Comment: thanks @Koen., so i guess the react.js rerender mechanism is that it only checks the type of element whether has changed to decide whether need to rerender the element. In my code, the LoginComponent return the same element type <Greeting />, so react.js thinks it doesn't need to new a new element, and keep using the first created Greeting Component element.

Answer (score 0):

Well to be honest the answer which I posted previously was wrong. It was because the way you posted the question telling that everything works fine when function based component is added. Then I created a project using your code and figured out few issues in your code.

Firstly you are maintaining state locally outside redux here. You are passing down the state of the login from the parent `LoginComponent` to the child component called Greeting like this.

```
greeting = <Greeting is_logon={this.state.is_logon} />
```

This gets passed as a props to the child component which is `Greeting` in this case. Remember React uses **one way data flow**.

Now from that child component you can access the data using `this.props` as shown below. You don't need to maintain any local state what so ever there.
Do the following changes in your `Greeting` component.

```
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }
```

Then make sure you access the values from this.props instead of any local state object like this.

```
 render() {
      let welcome_msg = null;
      if (this.props.is_logon) {
          welcome_msg = <GreetingUser />;
      }else {
          welcome_msg = <GreetingGuest />;
      }
      return welcome_msg;
  }
}
```

This solved the issue. Happy Coding !

Comment: Please explain why. Supllying pieces of code will probably not help the asker to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks. And now I can say that there's nothing wrong with the current render method, so this is probably not going to solve the problem.

Comment: According to what I see the render function in Greeting component merely returns a JavaScript variable, that would probably cause this issue in my opinion. return welcome_msg;

Comment: It does, and that is totally fine, since JSX just is syntactic sugar :)

Comment: Yeah you may be right. I was mislead by the way he explained it using the function component and saying that it is working fine. Some wired logic he has put to the button would cause this error i guess.

Comment: You should have posted it as a new answer instead of changing this one, because now the comments are out of context

Comment: ohh I am sorry! Is there a way that I can get the previous incarnation of my answer here?